# connecting sql server using jtds windows authentication from java

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I am facing problem with below connection string for java program to connect to windows authenticated login for sql server.
My system is 64 bit , so added the ntlmauth.dll from x64/sso/ to classpath

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.180.12:1433/product;useNTLMv2=true;user=sql_user;password=sql_pass;domain=SQLEXPRESS
```

It throws "**java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.**" exception.

I verified lot of Q&A from StackOverflow : changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost,using useNTLMv2 nothing helps me .

**PS:**
Please use **sql_user** for mentioning sql username **sql_pass** for sql password. **win_user** for windows username and **win_pass** for windows password.
Its confusing in lot of post what to use at where.